# How to check duplicate entry in listview through listbox?

Tags: c#

I have three controls on my form and I am transferring the data from listbox and combobox to listview but before transferring the data I want to check whether the data existed or not.
suppose I have an object in combobox "Car" and on the basis of its selected event I am fetching the types of car and filling into the listbox. so after selecting CAR I got the list of different-2 CAR's in my list box. when i double click on the "SKODA" car, the information CAR+SKODA transferring to the listview like -

```
Car | SKODA
Car | FARRARI
Car | Maruti SWIFT
```

but I don't want to duplicate the data in the listview....
like if someone is inserting

> "Car | Maruti SWIFT"

again then the ERROR message should occur .
so my code is -

Comment: You didn't provide any code samples

Comment: You haven't added the code.

Comment: my code is-
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (ListViewItem l in lvMI.Items)
{
if (l.SubItems[0].Text != "")
{
string group = l.SubItems[0].Text;
string item = l.SubItems[1].Text;
MessageBox.Show(group + " " + item);
if (cbSelectGroup.Text == group && listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == item)
{
MessageBox.Show("already selected");
}
}
else
{
string[] fillItems = { cbSelectGroup.Text, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() };
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fillItems);
lvMI.Items.Add(lvi);
return;
}
}
}
where,
lvMI is ListView
cbSelectGroup is ComboBox

Answer (score 1):

you can use the .Contains() method:

```
List<Car> carsList;
Car selectedCar;

if(!carsList.Contains(selectedCar)){
    carsList.Add(SelectedCar)
}
```

You can override the Equals method on your Car object to specify how to compare if the cars are the same.

Answer (score 0):

yeah of course your problem is solution **contains** property. contains are check out previous records in the list box.contains coding  here...
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!textBox1.Text.Contains("joginder"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate entry");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no duplicate entry");
        }


    }
```